# Mi programa de piedra papel o tijera en C++ tiene un problema

Tags: c++

Es un programa muy básico, se cierra después de una ronda. La parte del juego en sí funciona, pero le puse algo para que antes de cerrar te dijese si ganaste o perdiste. Pero tengo el problema de que 3 de los 7 if que usé para esto, es como si no existiesen. Cuando corro el programa simplemente son ignorados y no entiendo por qué. Traté cerrando y volviendo a abrir Visual Studio Code y volver a correr, se lo pasé a un amigo que tampoco pudo encontrar el error, y hasta hice el mismo programa en Turbo C y tuvo el mismo problema. ¿Alguien sabe por qué pasa esto? Les adjunto la parte de los if(maqui es la eleccion de la maquina, elec es la del usuario, pied es un char que dice "piedra", y lo mismo con tije(tijera) y pap(papel))

Editado: me pidieron que agregase la parte en la que se incluye el valor elec,aquí está. La variable opn es la variable que creé para asignarle un valor al azar a la elección de la máquina.
Pongo todo el código

```
 // Programa simple de piedra papel o tijera
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<funcfalt.cpp> //archivo que uso para reemplazar funciones del Turbo C


main() { 
int opn=0;
char elec[7], tije[]="tijera",pap[]="papel",pied[]="piedra",maqui[7];
clrscr();
printf("Bienvenido al juego virtual de piedra, papel o tijera");
printf("\n\nIngrese su jugada: ");
scanf("%s",&elec);
srand(time(NULL));
while(opn==0) { 
    opn = rand()%4;
}

switch(opn) {
    case 1: strcpy(maqui,pied);
    break;
    case 2: strcpy(maqui,tije);
    break;
    case 3: strcpy(maqui,pap);
    break;
}

printf("La maquina eligio %s",maqui);
if(strcmp(maqui,elec)==0) {
    printf("\nEmpate!");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,pied)==0&&strcmp(elec,tije)==0) {   //No aparece
    printf("Lo lamento, perdiste");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,tije)==0&&strcmp(elec,pap)==0) {
    printf("\nLo lamento, perdiste");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,pap)==0&&strcmp(elec,pied)==0) {
    printf("\nLo lamento, perdiste");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,tije)==0&&strcmp(elec,pied)==0) {  //No aparece
    printf("\nFelicidades, ganaste");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,pap)==0&&strcmp(elec,tije)==0) {
    printf("\nFelicidades, ganaste");
}

else if(strcmp(maqui,pied)==0&&strcmp(elec,pap)==0) {   //No aparece
    printf("\nFelicidades, ganaste");
}
else {
    main();
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo estas recibiendo los datos? Lo probé tal cual como lo tienes pero con valores estáticos y funcionan todas las validaciones

Comment: Tu código se parece más a C que a C++. ¿Tu profesor ha prohibido el uso de las funciones de C++?

Comment: Este código está bien, el error viene de otro lado. Por favor, incluye el código con el que lees la variable `elec` y el uso que haces de la misma, para ver de qué punto viene el fallo.

Comment: y las variables `maqui` y `elec`??

Comment: @eferion `maqui` y `elec` son variables de cadenas vacías a las que se les asigna un valor en la parte de arriba del código que publiqué

Comment: vale, pero son `std::string`?, array de char? de qué tamaño? punteros a char tal vez? si lo pregunto es porque puede ser importante

Comment: @eferion array de char, le puse tamaño 7

Comment: A ver, es importante que pongas **en la pregunta** toda la información importante. C++ es un lenguaje muy puñetero en el que una simple coma puede cambiar totalmente el resultado de una operación. El programa no parece ser mucho más largo que lo que hay ahora mismo en la pregunta... por favor, añade todo el código tal cual lo tengas

Comment: @eferion ya puse todo el código. Tienes idea de donde viene el problema?

Comment: ¿Qué funciones de turboC estás usando en ese código? Lo pregunto por si alguna de las funciones que veo ahí puede tener un comportamiento diferente al esperado. Es que no veo por qué va a ser necesaria la cabecera de `funcfalt.h`

Comment: @eferion ahí estoy usando la función 'clrscr()' y la tuve que agregar porque Visual Studio Code no me la reconocía usando las librerías que suelo usar. Ya sé que podría usar otras funciones que hacen lo mismo, pero me siento más cómodo usando esa.

Answer (score 1):

para este tipo de juegos es mejor prescindir de los if ya que lían bastante el código sobre todo si son muchas combinaciones. Así mismo dificulta la legibilidad del mismo.

La versión que muestro evita el uso de if con una simple función de comprobar donde he creado una matriz que ya nos revela el resultado en funcción de la opción elegida por la máquina y el usuario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Declaración nuestra función que nos devuelve
// el resultado del juego 0-Empate, 1-Perdiste, y 2-Ganaste
int Comprobar(int PC, int User);

int  main()
{ 
    int UserPlayer, PC_Player;
    char elemento[3][16] = { "PIEDRA", "PAPEL", "TIJERA" };
    char resultado[3][9] = { "EMPATE", "PERDISTE", "GANASTE" };
    //clrscr();
    printf("Bienvenido al juego virtual de Piedra, papel o tijera. ");
    printf("Elija una opción:\n (1) Piedra\n (2) Papel\n (3) Tijera\n");

    printf("\n\nIngrese su jugada: ");
    scanf("%d", &UserPlayer);

    srand(time(NULL));
    PC_Player = rand()%3;

    printf("\nLa maquina eligió %s y tú %s ->", elemento[PC_Player],
                                                elemento[UserPlayer-1]);
    printf("%s", resultado[Comprobar(PC_Player, UserPlayer-1)]);
    
    return 0;
}

int Comprobar(int PC, int User) 
{
    int MapJuego[3][3] = { {0, 2, 1},
                           {1, 0, 2},
                           {2, 1, 0} 
                         };
 
   return MapJuego[PC][User];
}
```

Comment: Es una solución interesante y te agradezco que te hayas tomado el tiempo de responderme, pero no estoy buscando una solución alternativa sino entender por qué pasa esto.

Comment: Prueba a poner los condicionales el símbolo && con espacio a ambos lados. Son simples comprobaciones no debiera de haber mayor problema. Por eso ofrecí la otra solución que evita engorros en el código.

Comment: tampoco me sirvió lo de los espacios. Sigue igual.

Comment: Prueba a sustituir strcmp (maqui, tije) == 0 por (opn ==2)

Comment: Mira he pasado tu código a un compilador online y tengo algunos problemas que me da error. Donde pones scanf("%s",&elec); tengo que poner scanf("%s",elec); Y he comprobado los estados que indicas que no aparece y sí aparece. Está correcto salvo el error que he indicado que es simplemente quitar el símbolo &. No entiendo que a tí te pueda funcionar el programa.